# Set the Treeview background image

Tags: c#

**i work on VS05 C#**
I have a treeview derived control, and I want this tree view to be
shown with a background image.What should I do in order to display a background image behind the tree and still view the tree nodes?

Answer (score 3):

the default TreeView control doesn't support backgrounds